# exepted identifier or '(' before '{' token error while compiling

Tags: list, linked-list

This might be a very stupid problem but i can't find a way to solve it.
i'm getting this error message while trying to compile this program:
Exercise1.c:28.1:exepted identifier or '(' before '{' token.
Can you please explain what am i doing wrong? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct II_node_struct
{int info;
 struct II_node_struct *next;}II_node;

II_node* push(II_node* lis,int);
II_node* pop(II_node* lis);

int main()
{
 II_node* pila;
 II_node* corr=pila;
  int x;
 while(x>=0)
 {scanf(" %d",&x);
  if(x>0)
  corr=push(corr,x);
  if(x==0)
  corr=pop(corr);}
 while(corr->next!=NULL)
 {printf("%d\n",corr->info);
  corr=corr->next;}
 return 0;
}

II_node* pop(II_node* lis);
{
 II_node* risultato;
 if(lis==NULL)
  risultato=lis;
 if(lis->next==NULL)
  {risultato=lis;
   free(lis);}
 else
 {risultato=lis->next;
  free(lis);}
 return risultato;
}

II_node* push(II_node* lis,int x)
{
 II_node* new=malloc(sizeof(II_node));
 if(lis==NULL)
 {lis=new;
  new->next=NULL;
  new->info=x;}
 else
 {new->next=lis;
  lis=new;}
 return lis;
}
```

Comment: May I suggest that you _format_ your code so that it is readable, which alone might make the syntax problem obvious?

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: The problem is located in the definition of **`II_node* pop(II_node* lis);`**. Remove the extra **`;`** (_only needed in the function declaration_). Warning, be careful when using variable names in the function `push(II_node* lis,int x)`, the name `new` is a reserved keyword of C++ and could occur some error/warning depending of the used compiler.